# Date Formatting 12/31 incorrectly adding a year

Tags: visualforce

I have the following Visualforce:

```
<block>
   <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(numYears>=1,true,false)}" value="{0,date,MM/dd/YY} to {1,date,MM/dd/YY}">
      <apex:param value="{!quote.MYD01_Start_Date__c}"/>
      <apex:param value="{!quote.MYD01_End_Date__c}"/>
   </apex:outputText>
</block>
```

When MYD01_End_Date__c = 12/30/19, it correctly shows 12/30/**19**.

When MYD01_End_Date__c = 12/31/19, it **incorrectly** shows 12/31/**20**.

Just testing, when I add the MYD01_End_Date__c outside of the param:

```
<block>
   <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(numYears>=1,true,false)}" value="{0,date,MM/dd/YY} to {1,date,MM/dd/YY}">
      <apex:param value="{!quote.MYD01_Start_Date__c}"/>
      <apex:param value="{!quote.MYD01_End_Date__c}"/>
      {!quote.MYD01_End_Date__c}
   </apex:outputText>

</block>
```

It shows Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 20**19**

So it appears only when I have the MYD01_End_Date__c in the apex:param and attempt to format it into mm/dd/yy and only when the date is December 31st that the year changes.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you should use *lower-case* `y` to represent year. The behavior of upper-case `Y` is not documented on that page.